# Pagination in Spring Book JPA with Nested loops

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, pagination

I am trying to implement Pagination. I am having two tables, a teacher and a student. For each teacher, there are multiple students. Now I got a list of TeacherNames and for each teacher, I have to find all its students and add them to the list, and finally return it. I am getting page number and size also as input.

```
List<TeacherEntity> teacher = TeacherRepo.findByName(TeacherNames);
Teachers.forEach(teacher - > {
    List<Student> students = studentRepo.findByTeacherName(teacher);
    studentDTO.addAll(students);
});

return StudentDTO;
```

I know how to implement pagination if I had to query only in teachersRepo. But I am not able to get how will I do it when there is nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have @ManyToMany relationship between student and teacher. If not, you have to create one before you proceed. Sample code to create relation

```
public class Teacher
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long teacherId;
    
    //some fields
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "teacher_student", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "teacherId", referencedColumnName = "techerId") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "studentId", referencedColumnName = "studentId") })

    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    private Set<Stident> students = new HashSet<>();
//Get and set
}
```

Now, in teacher repo, add a method having join between student and teacher

```
@Repository
public interface TeacherRepo extends JpaRepository<Teacher, Long>
{   
    @Query(value="SELECT t.teacherName,s.studentName FROM Teacher t left join t.students s")
    public ArrayList<User> findByStudent(Pageable paging);
}
```

Call this repo method in your sevice class

```
public ArrayList<Teacher> findByStudent() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(0, 4);
        return teacherRepo.findByStudent(paging);
    }
```

This way you pagination will return 4 students records.

Note - You can add where conditions, paginations, sorting details according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks a ton, Sridhar for your answer, I have one doubt. Is it necessary to write our own custom query, I mean can't we just use the JPA implementation

Comment: That is not a custom query, thats a JPQL. If you meant why we are writing JPQL, it is because your requirement is not directly handled by any ready to use method. If you had to fetch pagnation for teacher, you can use pageable directly with findall(). But since you want pagination based on child entity, you need to write your jpql

Comment: Pageable page = PageRequest.of(pageNo, size);

List<TeacherEntity> teacher = TeacherRepo.findByName(TeacherNames);
Teachers.forEach(teacher - > {
    List<Student> students = studentRepo.findByTeacherName(teacher, page);
    studentDTO.addAll(students);
});

return StudentDTO;

Comment: Can't I do like this? By this, I don't have to write JPQL

Comment: No. this will not work. suppose you want to fetch a total of 4 students in one page. Logic you written will fetch 4 student per teacher. Also, returning list will not return important details like current offset, total records, sorting applied etc which are very important for front end